# Java Compiler thinks byte[] is String

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, byte

I don't understand why java.lang.String cannot be converted in byte[].

On the line:

```
byte[] decData = io.decrypt(fileData, new Random(fileData.length));
```

my compiler said: java.lang.String cannot be converted in byte[]

but I initialise fileData like this:

```
byte[] fileData = new byte[fIn.available()];
```

And io.decrypt is defined like this:

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] data, Random key) {
    byte[] byteKey = new byte[data.length];
    key.nextBytes(byteKey);
    return decrypt(data, byteKey);
}
```

With Random being java.util.Random

So I don't understand why I did wrong.

Btw: I'm trying to make a simple XOR en/de-crypter

And this is the complete code:

```
    Boolean decrypt = praseBoolean(Greenfoot.ask("decrypt? (y/n)"));

    //Random rand = new Random();

    if(!decrypt) {
        File folder = new File("decrypted");
        File[] toEncrypt = folder.listFiles();
        //Long[] keys = 
        for(File file: toEncrypt) {
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] fileData = new byte[fIn.available()];
            fIn.read(fileData);
            byte[] encData = io.encrypt(fileData, new Random(fileData.length));
            io.saveEncryptedFile(encData, "encrypted/"+file.getName());
        }
    }

    if(decrypt) {
        File folder = new File("encrypted");
        File[] toEncrypt = folder.listFiles();
        //Long[] keys = 
        for(File file: toEncrypt) {
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] fileData = new byte[fIn.available()];
            fIn.read(fileData);
            byte[] decData = io.decrypt(fileData, new Random(fileData.length));
            io.saveEncryptedFile(encData, "decrypted/"+file.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to store a `String` into a `byte[]`? Check your `decrypt` return type...

Comment: I just forgot about that. My compiler isn't that good and selected the arguments so I looked at those puzzled.

Comment: Note that a `String` is not (logically) a `byte[]`: it is more like a `char[]`. Chars and bytes are not the same thing.

Comment: And just for the record: *compilers* dont think. They **take** your input and match it against the rules of the language. So when the compiler complains to you, it is because *you* wrote down something that doesn't make sense. Thus: when you think the compiler "thinks" strange: look at your code carefully. And read those error messages. Google them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`io.decrypt` returns `String`, but you assign the result to a `byte[]`. So change it to

```
byte[] decData = io.decrypt(fileData, new Random(fileData.length)).getBytes();
```

**or**

```
String decData = io.decrypt(fileData, new Random(fileData.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

`decrypt` returns a `String`, but you're trying to assign it to `byte[] decData`. Just assing it to a `String`, and you should be OK:

```
String decData = io.decrypt(fileData, new Random(fileData.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your decrypt method returns a `String`. If you want to get a byte array from that, use `string.getBytes()` on the result of your method, or return a byte array in the first place.